# Send values from django server to client?

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to give some values to my client (to use them in javascript) from my [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) server.

I know that I can use [cookies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/), but the problem is that they are kept for all request whereas I need them only once when the client loads for the first time (it is not really a problem).

I could also pass those values to the template to render some html tags with the "data-value-name" properties set the the values (for example `<body data-name="joe" data-id="123456">`)

Both solutions work fine, but is there a better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do is to create a `<script>` element where I render the values directly to JavaScript objects stored in local or global variables.

If you have a lot of values you can also consider implementing a view that returns JSON which is requested via ajax from the client.

Comment: The usage of `<script>` and directly creating JS-objects is really smart! +1 But I would go with a specific JSON-view, as you recommend in your second paragraph!

Comment: I think it depends on the use case. The `<script>` I used mainly to pass configuration to my JavaScript application, whereas the JSON stuff for sending larger amount of data or data that is queried repeatedly.